# How can I waterproof a tile soaking tub?

Tags: bathroom, waterproofing

I'm in California.

I want to build a tile soaking tub in an upcoming bathroom remodel but I'm unsure how I should waterproof it.

I recently was at a spa where they had deep and narrow soaking tubs which seemed to be built of cinder blocks which had been tiled.
These were in a concrete bath house, so I imagine slight leaks were not a big deal.

I want to put a similar tub in my bathroom, which is on wood subfloor with crawlspace below. Ignoring weight issues, can I do this without a tub shell? Kerdi membrane isn't rated for submersion water proofing nor is redgard as far as I can tell.

How might I go about this?